# Element not found error in Pop up iframe in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, select, automated-tests

I am trying to find input element which is of type **file** which is present in Pop up Iframe. But whenever I try to find that element it is giving me element not found error. Could somebody help me out in this regard?

Comment: Post your code and html.

Comment: Have you switched to iframe, before checking for the element?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to appropriate iframe and find your element in that frame.

Example ::

//By executing a java script

```
 JavascriptExecutor exe = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 Integer numberOfFrames = Integer.parseInt(exe.executeScript("return window.length").toString());
 System.out.println("Number of iframes on the page are " + numberOfFrames);

 //By finding all the web elements using iframe tag
 List<WebElement> iframeElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
 System.out.println("The total number of iframes are " + iframeElements.size());
```

Comment: Iframe is generated dynamically hence  driver.findElements not going to work.